# Can't handle synchronization in javascript function

Tags: javascript, overriding

I am overriding a javascript function like this :

```
(function() {
    origFunc = aFunction;
    aFunction = function() {
        doRequest();                
        //return origFunc.apply(this);
    };
})();
```

I know that I need to end the function with "return origFunc.apply(this)" in order to execute the original function. However, as I'm executing a request, I have to wait until the request is done. That's why I wrote this function :

```
doRequest: function()
{
    try
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        else if(window.ActiveXObject)
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        var url = anUrl, self = this;

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(data)
        {
            try
            {
                if(httpRequest.readyState == 4)
                {
                    if(httpRequest.status == 200)
                       return origFunc.apply(self);
                    else if(httpRequest.status != 0 )
                       alert("Error while executing the request : "+httpRequest.status+"\r\nUrl : "+url);
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {                    
            }
        };

        httpRequest.open("GET", url);
        httpRequest.send();
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        alert("Error : "+err);
    }        
}
```

As you can guess, the problem is that I can't do the things like that.
Do you know how I could do ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your problem is here. Can you explain this better?

Comment: To sum up, I'd like to execute the original function once the request is successfully done. So I can't do it like I said in the first part of my question.

Comment: What's keeping you from doing it. It's definitely possible, so what's your specific problem with making it happen?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. If I do it like in the first part of my question, the original function is executed even if the request is not done.

Comment: Your `doRequest` function, since it's running asynchronously, will have to take a callback as an argument. That callback you can wrap and then call the original callback, similarly to your first example. That's all there is to it.

Comment: I think I see what you want to say. Could you give a small example please ?

Comment: I just gave you an example. If it was helpful, it would be nice if you could accept that answer. Otherwise, please indicate where you experience problems understanding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for how to deal with wrapping async functions

```
// This simply calls the callback with some data after a second
// Could be an AJAX call for example
var doSomethingAsync = function (callback) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    callback({ some: 'data' });
  }, 1000);
};

var fnThatMakesAsyncCall = function () {
  // From the outside there is no way to change this callback
  // But what if we need to intercept the async function to change the data given to it, or monitor it?
  // Then we'd have to wrap the async function to wrap the callback.
  var callback = function (data) {
    console.log('Original', data); 
  };

  doSomethingAsync(callback);
};

// Function to wrap another function and return the wrapper
var wrapFn = function (fn) {
  // Create the wrapped function.
  // Notice how it has the same signature with `callback` as the first argument
  var wrapped = function (callback) {
    // Here we get the original callback passed in
    // We will instead wrap that too and call the original function with our new callback
    var newCb = function (data) {
      // This will run once the async call is complete
      // We will as an example mutate the data in the return data of the callback
      data.some = 'Wrapped it';
      // Call the original callback with the changed data
      callback.call(this, data);
    };
    // Run the function we wrap with the new callback we supply
    fn.call(this, newCb);
  };
  // Return wrapped function
  return wrapped;
};

// Will log Original {some: "data"} 
fnThatMakesAsyncCall();
doSomethingAsync = wrapFn(doSomethingAsync);
// Will log Original {some: "Wrapped it"} 
fnThatMakesAsyncCall();
```